# _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-initaldir": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, or -typevariable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting this error on Tkinter and I don't how to solve it any help is appreciated.

```py
def choose_file():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initaldir= '/pictures', title= "Select a file", 
                     filetypes= (("csv files", "*.csv"), ("excel files", "*.xlsx"),("all files", "*.*")))
    the_file = root.filename


button1 = Button(root, text= "Choose File", command= choose_file)
button1.place(x= 256, y= 290, width= 94, height= 50)
```

**Error:**

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Norbert Dias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "app1.py", line 23, in choose_file
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initaldir= '/pictures', title= "Select a file", filetypes= (("csv files", "*.csv"), ("excel files", "*.xlsx"),("all files", "*.*")))
  File "C:\Users\Norbert Dias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 376, in askopenfilename
    return Open(\**options).show()
  File "C:\Users\Norbert Dias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 44, in show
    s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
```

**Main Part**

```py
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-initaldir": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -multiple, -parent, -title, or -typevariable
```

Comment: The error has show you that you have a typo.It should be `initialdir` instead of `initaldir`.Check your word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simplay misspelled "initialdir" because you forgot the third "i". Please check for any typing mistakes in your code first before you submit an question to Stackoverflow. ^^

PS: Maybe ask someone else to look over your code. Four eyes see more than 2!